# How to infer the type of an expression manually

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, unification

Given ist the Haskell function:

```
head . filter fst
```

The question is now how to find the type "manually" by hand. If I let Haskell tell me the type I get:

```
head . filter fst :: [(Bool, b)] -> (Bool, b)
```

But I want to understand how this works using only the signatures of the used functions which are defined as follows:

```
head :: [a] -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

*Edit: so many very good explanations ... it's not easy to select the best one!*

Answer (score 19):

Types are infered using a process generally called [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29).
Haskell belongs to the [Hindley-Milner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner) family, which is the unification
algorithm it uses to determine the type of an expression.

If unification fails, then the expression is a type error.

The expression

```
head . filter fst
```

passes. Let's do the unification manually to see what why we get
what we get.

Let's start with `filter fst`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst :: (a' , b') -> a'                -- using a', b' to prevent confusion
```

`filter` takes a `(a -> Bool)`, then a `[a]` to give another `[a]`. In the expression 
`filter fst`, we pass to `filter` the argument `fst`, whose type is `(a', b') -> a'`.
For this to work, the type `fst` *must unify* with the type of `filter`'s first argument:

```
(a -> Bool)  UNIFY?  ((a', b') -> a')
```

The algorithm *unifies* the two type expressions and tries to *bind* as many type *variables* (such as `a` or `a'`) to actual types (such as `Bool`).

Only then does `filter fst` lead to a valid typed expression:

```
filter fst :: [a] -> [a]
```

`a'` is clearly `Bool`. So the type *variable* `a'` resolves to a `Bool`.
And `(a', b')` can unify to `a`. So if `a` is `(a', b')` and `a'` is `Bool`,
Then `a` is just `(Bool, b')`.

If we had passed an incompatible argument to `filter`, such as `42` (a `Num`),
unification of `Num a => a` with `a -> Bool` would have failed as the two expressions
can never unify to a correct type expression.

Coming back to

```
filter fst :: [a] -> [a]
```

This is the same `a` we are talking about, so we substitute in it's place
the result of the previous unification:

```
filter fst :: [(Bool, b')] -> [(Bool, b')]
```

The next bit,

```
head . (filter fst)
```

Can be written as

```
(.) head (filter fst)
```

So take `(.)`

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So for unification to succeed,

1. `head :: [a] -> a` must unify `(b -> c)`
2. `filter fst  :: [(Bool, b')] -> [(Bool, b')]` must unify `(a -> b)`

From (2) we get that `a` **IS** `b` in the expression 
`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`)`

So the values of the type variables `a` and `c` in the
expression `(.) head (filter fst) :: a -> c` are easy to tell since
(1) gives us the relation between `b` and `c`, that: `b` is a list of `c`.
And as we know `a` to be `[(Bool, b')]`, `c` can only unify to `(Bool, b')`

So `head . filter fst` successfully type-checks as that:

```
head . filter fst ::  [(Bool, b')] -> (Bool, b')
```

**UPDATE**

It's interesting to see how you can unify starting the process from various points.
I chose `filter fst` first, then went on to `(.)` and `head` but as the other examples
show, unification can be carried out in several ways, not unlike the way a mathematic
proof or a theorem derivation can be done in more than one way!

Comment: A minor nit: if you passed `42` as an argument to `filter`, unification would succeed, resulting in the literal `42` having the type `forall a. Num (a->Bool):: a->Bool`.  Much later in the process, ghc would then report that there's no valid `instance Num (a->Bool)` in scope.  This has practical consequences, as errors like this are somewhat common in practice, and it's useful to understand why ghc produces this error instead of something more helpful.

Answer (score 11):

`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` takes a function `(a -> Bool)`, a list of the same type `a`, and also returns a list of that type `a`.

In your defintion you use `filter fst` with `fst :: (a,b) -> a` so the type

```
filter (fst :: (Bool,b) -> Bool) :: [(Bool,b)] -> [(Bool,b)]
```

is inferred.
Next, you compose your result `[(Bool,b)]` with `head :: [a] -> a`.

`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` is the composition of two functions, `func2 :: (b -> c)` and `func1 :: (a -> b)`. In your case, you have

```
func2 = head       ::               [ a      ]  -> a
```

and

```
func1 = filter fst :: [(Bool,b)] -> [(Bool,b)]
```

so `head` here takes `[(Bool,b)]` as argument and returns `(Bool,b)` per definition. In the end you have:

```
head . filter fst :: [(Bool,b)] -> (Bool,b)
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's start with `(.)`. It's type signature is

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

which says
"given a function from `b` to `c`, and a function from `a` to `b`,
and an `a`, I can give you a `b`". We want to use that with `head` and
`filter fst`, so`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
       ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^
         head     filter fst
```

Now `head`, which is a function from an array of something to a 
single something. So now we know that `b` is going to be an array,
and `c` is going to be an element of that array. So for the purpose of
our expression, we can think of `(.)` as having the signature:

```
(.) :: ([d] -> d) -> (a -> [d]) -> a -> d -- Equation (1)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
                     filter fst
```

The signature for `filter` is:

```
filter :: (e -> Bool) -> [e] -> [e] -- Equation (2)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
              fst
```

(Note that I've changed the name of the type variable to avoid confusion
with the `a`s
that we already have!) This says "Given a function from `e` to a Bool,
and a list of `e`s, I can give you a list of `e`s". The function `fst`
has the signature:

```
fst :: (f, g) -> f
```

says, "given a pair containing an `f` and a `g`, I can give you an `f`".
Comparing this with Equation 2, we know that
`e` is going to be a pair of values, the first element of
which must be a `Bool`. So in our expression, we can think of `filter`
as having the signature:

```
filter :: ((Bool, g) -> Bool) -> [(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]
```

(All I've done here is to replace `e` with `(Bool, g)` in Equation 2.)
And the expression `filter fst` has the type:

```
filter fst :: [(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]
```

Going back to Equation 1, we can see that `(a -> [d])` must now be
`[(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]`, so `a` must be `[(Bool, g)]` and `d`
must be `(Bool, g)`. So in our expression, we can think of `(.)` as
having the signature:

```
(.) :: ([(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)) -> ([(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]) -> [(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)
```

To summarise:

```
(.) :: ([(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)) -> ([(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]) -> [(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                head                         filter fst
head :: [(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)
filter fst :: [(Bool, g)] -> [(Bool, g)]
```

Putting it all together:

```
head . filter fst :: [(Bool, g)] -> (Bool, g)
```

Which is equivalent to what you had, except that I've used `g` as the type variable rather than `b`.

This probably all sounds very complicated, because I described it in gory detail. However, this sort of reasoning quickly becomes second nature and you can do it in your head.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>(skip down for a *manual* derivation)</sup>

*Find the type of `head . filter fst` == `((.) head) (filter fst)`, given*

```
head   :: [a] -> a
(.)    :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a])
fst    :: (a, b) -> a
```

This is achieved *in a purely mechanical manner* by a small Prolog program:

```
type(head,    arrow(list(A)       , A)).                 %% -- known facts
type(compose, arrow(arrow(B, C)   , arrow(arrow(A, B), arrow(A, C)))).
type(filter,  arrow(arrow(A, bool), arrow(list(A)    , list(A)))).
type(fst,     arrow(pair(A, B)    , A)).

type([F, X], T):- type(F, arrow(A, T)), type(X, A).      %% -- application rule
```

which automagically produces, when run in a Prolog interpreter,

```
3 ?- type([[compose, head], [filter, fst]], T).
T = arrow(list(pair(bool, A)), pair(bool, A))       %% -- [(Bool,a)] -> (Bool,a)
```

where types are represented as compound data terms, in a purely syntactical manner. E.g. the type `[a] -> a` is represented by `arrow(list(A), A)`, with possible Haskell equivalent `Arrow (List (Logvar "a")) (Logvar "a")`, given the appropriate `data` definitions.

Only one inference rule, that of an ***application***, was used, as well as Prolog's ***structural unification*** whereby *compound terms* match if they have the same shape and their constituents match: *f(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ... a<sub>n</sub>)* and *g(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ... b<sub>m</sub>)* match iff *f* is the same as *g*, *n == m* and *a<sub>i</sub>* matches  *b<sub>i</sub>*, with logical variables being able to take on any value as needed, but only *once* (can't be changed).

```
4 ?- type([compose, head], T1).     %% -- (.) head   :: (a -> [b]) -> (a -> b)
T1 = arrow(arrow(A, list(B)), arrow(A, B))

5 ?- type([filter, fst], T2).       %% -- filter fst :: [(Bool,a)] -> [(Bool,a)]
T2 = arrow(list(pair(bool, A)), list(pair(bool, A)))
```

---

To perform type inference ***manually*** in a mechanical fashion, involves writing things one under another, noting equivalences on the side and performing the substitutions thus mimicking the operations of Prolog. We can treat any `->, (_,_), []` etc. purely as syntactical markers, without understanding their meaning at all, and perform the process mechanically using structural unification and, here, only one [rule of type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Typing_rules), viz. rule of *application*: **`(a -> b) c ⊢ b {a ~ c}`** (replace a juxtaposition of `(a -> b)` and `c`, with `b`, under the equivalence of `a` and `c`). It is important to rename logical variables, consistently, to avoid name clashes:

```
(.)  :: (b    -> c ) -> ((a -> b  ) -> (a -> c ))           b ~ [a1], 
head ::  [a1] -> a1                                         c ~ a1
(.) head ::              (a ->[a1]) -> (a -> c ) 
                         (a ->[c] ) -> (a -> c ) 
---------------------------------------------------------
filter :: (   a    -> Bool) -> ([a]        -> [a])          a ~ (a1,b), 
fst    ::  (a1, b) -> a1                                    Bool ~ a1
filter fst ::                   [(a1,b)]   -> [(a1,b)]  
                                [(Bool,b)] -> [(Bool,b)] 
---------------------------------------------------------
(.) head   :: (      a    -> [     c  ]) -> (a -> c)        a ~ [(Bool,b)]
filter fst ::  [(Bool,b)] -> [(Bool,b)]                     c ~ (Bool,b)
((.) head) (filter fst) ::                   a -> c      
                                    [(Bool,b)] -> (Bool,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this the "technical" way, with lots of complicated unification steps. Or you can do it the "intuitive" way, just looking at the thing and thinking "OK, what have I got here? What is this expecting?" and so on.

Well, `filter` expects a function and a list, and returns a list. `filter fst` specifies a function, but there's no list given - so we're still waiting for the list input. So `filter fst` is taking a list and returning another list. (This is quite a common Haskell phrase, by the way.)

Next, the `.` operator "pipes" the output to `head`, which expects a list and returns one of the elements from that list. (The first one, as it happens.) So whatever `filter` comes up with, `head` gives you the first element of it. At this point, we can conclude

```
head . filter foobar :: [x] -> x
```

But what is `x`? Well, `filter fst` applies `fst` to every element of the list (to decide whether to keep it or throw it). So `fst` must be applicable to the list elements. And `fst` expects a 2-element tuple, and returns the first element of that tuple. Now `filter` is expecting `fst` to return a `Bool`, so that means the first element of the tuple must be a `Bool`.

Putting all that together, we conclude

```
head . filter fst :: [(Bool, y)] -> (Bool, y)
```

What is `y`? We don't know. We don't actually care! The above functions will work whatever it is. So that's our type signature.

---

In more complicated examples it can be harder to figure out what's going on. (Especially when weird class instances get involved!) But for smallish ones like this, involving common functions, you can usually just think "OK, what goes in here? What comes out there? What does this function expect?" and walk right up to the answer without too much manual algorithm-chasing.