# Why has "map (filter fst)" the type "[[(Bool, a)]] -> [[(Bool, a)]]"?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference, unification

I'm trying to understand why the function

```
map (filter fst)
```

has the type

```
[[(Bool, a)]] -> [[(Bool, a)]]
```

How can "filter fst" work if filter must receive a function which returns a Bool-Type and fst just returns the first element of a tuple?

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

Can anyone explains me? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can "filter fst" work if filter must receive a function which returns a Bool-Type and fst just returns the first element of a tuple?

In a sense, you've answered your own question!  Let's break it down:

> filter must receive a function which returns a Bool-Type

OK, so let's look at what you're passing it: `fst`.  Is `fst` a function?  Yes, it is, so we've got the first part down.  Does it return a `Bool`?  Well, let's look at what it does:

> fst just returns the first element of a tuple

So if the first element of a tuple is a `Bool`, then yes, it does return a bool!  If  the first element of a tuple is anything other than a `Bool`, though, it doesn't and will fail the typecheck.

Let's have another look at the types you put up.  I'm going to change the names of the type variables just to make things clearer:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst :: (b, c) -> b
```

`fst` takes an `(b, c)` and returns an `b`, and filter is expecting a function which takes an `a` and returns a `Bool`.  We are passing in `fst`, so the `a` above must be `(b, c)` as that's the first parameter of `fst`.  The return value of the function we pass into `filter` must be a `Bool`, so `b` above must therefore be a `Bool`.  And `c` can be anything, because it's not used by filter at all.  Substituting the values for `a` and `b` gives us a final type for `filter fst` of:

```
filter fst :: [(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]
```

Finally, the type of `map` is:

```
map :: (d -> e) -> [d] -> [e]
```

(Again, I've renamed the type variables here, just to differentiate them from the ones we've used above, but remember it doesn't actually matter what they're called so long as they're consistent within the scope of the type annotation)

`map (filter fst)` passes the `filter fst` we defined above as the first parameter to `map`.  Substituting the parameter for `d` and the result for `e` we can see this function must be `[(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]`, in other words both `d` and `e` are `(Bool, c)`.  Plugging those into the function we arrive at the final type:

```
map (filter fst) :: [[(Bool, c)]] -> [[(Bool, c)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`fst` is a function that returns a boolean as long as you restrict the tuples to  have a Boolean as their first element (the second element can be anything, hence the `(Bool, a)`

Answer (score 1):

```
:t filter    -- (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
:t fst       -- (a,b) -> a
```

But, we could also exchange type variables for `fst` to get:

```
:t fst       -- (c,b) -> c
```

So, the first argument of `filter` has type `a -> Bool`, while `fst` itself is `(c,b) -> c`. Now we try to combine this (I think this is called unification):

```
1st arg of filter:  a     -> Bool
fst:                (c,b) -> c
```

From this, we can infer that `c` must be `Bool` (since the right hand side has to be equal) and obtain:

```
1st arg of filter:  a        -> Bool
fst:                (Bool,b) -> Bool
```

From the above, we infer that `a` must be `(Bool,b)`, and obtain:

```
1st arg of filter:  (Bool,b) -> Bool
fst:                (Bool,b) -> Bool
```

And we are done.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "restriction" (i.e. restricting the type of a type variable). The term "unification" is used in logic programming. It is an execution strategy which works by unifying variables in logical predicates such that they make the logical predicate true. To put it simply "unification" is a trial and error process. It's used to determine the validity of values. In contrast "restriction" is not a trial and error process. It's like a one-shot assignment process. While the two are similar concepts they are definitely not the same.

Comment: @AaditMShah: No, this is unification; for a source, [I'll provide Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).  It's not true that unification is "trial and error".  Unification is, [to quote the Wikipedia redirect page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification), "the act of identifying two terms with a suitable substitution".  You could do this via trial and error, but Hindley-Milner uses a principled unification algorithm.  (I think logic programming is more principled than just "trial and error" as well , but I don't know any details here.)

Comment: @AaditMShah, there is a very close connection between type systems and formal logics; as a result, there is a very close connection between type checking and logic language implementation.

Comment: @AaditMShah no, *backtracking* is a trial-and-error process. Unification is deterministic. You just explore both trees branch by branch.

Comment: @WillNess Unification makes use of backtracking. Thereby unification is non-deterministic. Logic programming is non-deterministic. If it were deterministic then it would be proof that P=NP. Research in the field of quantum computing would be rendered moot, asymmetric key cryptography would no longer be secure and the verisimilitude of the existence of the improbability drive from The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy would no longer be fallacious. Don't believe me? Confirm it for yourself: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6

Comment: @AaditMShah no, it's the other way around. Resolution is performed by unification of terms, selected from the program database (aka "knowledge base") in a backtrackable fashion. Selection from database is not part of unification of logical terms. --- Look at your own link: :) it says "Now that we know about unification", i.e. it is described in the *previous* link.

Comment: @WillNess Ah, that evinced my mistake. Unification is indeed separate from proof search. I was under the impression that the two could not be disparate.

Comment: @AaditMShah I invite you to peruse [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14558244/849891) for your enjoyment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I already wrote this down before danielpwright's answer was posted, I post it anyway. I'm just going through my thought process for the type of `filter fst` here.

First, write down the type signatures (change fst so that its type variable names don't clash with those of filter):

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst :: (b, c) -> b
```

Match `(a -> Bool)` with `((b, c) -> b)` :

`b` has to be `Bool`, which means that `a` has to be `(Bool,c)`

By specializing `filter` with this information it becomes:

```
filter :: ((Bool,c) -> Bool) -> [(Bool,c)] -> [(Bool,c)]
```

which leads to

```
filter fst :: [(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You really just have to solve some type equations. Let's start:

```
 filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
 fst    :: (b, c) -> b
```

Therefore, `filter fst :: [a] -> [a]` where `a` is the solution of the following type equation:

```
 a -> Bool = (b, c) -> b
```

which implies

```
 a    = (b, c)
 Bool = b
```

which implies

```
 a = (Bool, c)
```

Therefore, `filter fst :: [(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]`.

Now we have:

```
map        :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
filter fst :: [(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]
```

So, `map (filter fst) :: [a] -> [b]` where `a` and `b` are given by the following type equation:

```
a -> b = [(Bool, c)] -> [(Bool, c)]
```

which implies

```
a = [(Bool, c)]
b = [(Bool, c)]
```

Therefore, `map (filter fst) :: [[(Bool, c)]] -> [[(Bool, c)]]`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have done, I want to solve the type equations here; but I want to write them down in a more visual way, so the derivation can be performed in a more automatic way. Let's see.

```
filter :: (  a   -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
fst    ::  (c,d) -> c              -- always use unique type var names, 
------------------------           --   rename freely but consistently
filter fst :: [a] -> [a],    a -> Bool  ~  (c,d) -> c
                             a ~ (c,d)  ,  Bool ~ c
                             a ~ (Bool,d)
           ---------------------------
           :: [(Bool,d)] -> [(Bool,d)]
```

Purely mechanical stuff. :) With this,

```
map        :: (     a     ->     b     ) -> [a] -> [b]
filter fst ::  [(Bool,d)] -> [(Bool,d)]
------------------------------
map (filter fst) :: [a] -> [b],     a ~ [(Bool,d)]  ,  b ~ [(Bool,d)]
                 -------------------------------
                 :: [[(Bool,d)]] -> [[(Bool,d)]]
```

The type variables in the final type can be freely renamed for readability (in a consistent manner of course).

The only thing that my answer adds to what was already shown in other answers here, is this advice (which I think important): *if you follow this simple discipline of **writing down one thing below the other**, it becomes very easy to perform these type unifications in very mechanical, automatic manner (thus reducing possibility of error).*

For another example of this, including an actual type-deriving Prolog program, see [*Haskell: how to infer the type of an expression manually*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558244/849891).