# Understanding foldTree function's type derivation

Tags: haskell, types, tree, type-inference, fold

Looking at this definition appearing in `Data.Tree`:

```hs
foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f = go where
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

My specific question is: as `go` name appears in the right-hand side of the equation in `(map go ts)`, how is the type of the function

```hs
(a -> [b] -> b)
```

being inferred ?

For example, having this line of code:

```hs
foldTree (:) (Node 1 [Node 2 []])
```

an instantiating the definition:

```hs
foldTree (:) = go where
    go (Node 1 [Node 2 []]) = (:) 1 (map go [Node 2 []])
```

`(:) 1 (map go [Node 2 []])` is not fully evaluated, so I just see `(:) 1` having the type `Num a => [a] -> [a]`. However, there is one gap missing and, in order to fill it, the recursion should be completed. So, there seems to be some circularity for calculating the type.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: The type of `go` is `Tree a -> b`. The only thing of type `(a -> [b] -> b)` is `f`, and that type comes right out of the type signature in the code.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how is `f` type being inferred since only its first argument is filled. The second argument is the mapping of `go` function across its subtree.

Comment: The type signature of `foldTree` is not needed to infer its type. Type inference in Haskell is more clever than you imagine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell's type inference is very clever! I can't tell you how this actually gets inferred, but let's walk through how it might be. The reality is probably not too far off. The type signature is actually not required in this case.

```
foldTree f = go where
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

`foldTree` is defined to take an argument, and `go` is defined to take an argument, so we know right from the start that these are functions.

```hs
foldTree :: _a -> _b
foldTree f = go where
    go :: _c -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

Now we see that `f` is called with two arguments, so it must actually be a function of (at least) two arguments.

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> _y -> _z) -> _b
foldTree f = go where
    go :: _c -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

Since `foldTree f = go`, and `go :: _c -> _d`, the result type `_b` must actually be `_c -> _d` *:

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> _y -> _z) -> _c -> _d
foldTree f = go where
    go :: _c -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

The second argument passed to `f` (of type `_y`) is `map go ts`. Since `go :: _c -> _d`, `_y` must be `[_d]`

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> [_d] -> _z) -> _c -> _d
foldTree f = go where
    go :: _c -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

`go` matches its argument against `Node x ts`, and `Node` is a data constructor for `Tree`, so `go`'s argument (`_c`) must be a `Tree`.

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> [_d] -> _z) -> Tree _p -> _d
foldTree f = go where
    go :: Tree _p -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

The first field of the `Node` constructor is passed as the first argument of `f`, so `_x` and `_p` must be the same:

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> [_d] -> _z) -> Tree _x -> _d
foldTree f = go where
    go :: Tree _x -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

Since `go _` is defined as `f _ _`, they must have results of the same type, so `_z` is `_d`:

```hs
foldTree :: (_x -> [_d] -> _d) -> Tree _x -> _d
foldTree f = go where
    go :: Tree _x -> _d
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

Whew. Now the compiler checks to make sure these types work out (which they do), and it "generalizes" them from "metavariables" (variables that mean the inference engine doesn't know what type they represent) to quantified type variables (variables that are definitely polymorphic), and it gets

```hs
foldTree :: forall a b. (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f = go where
    go :: Tree a -> b
    go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
```

The reality is a bit more complicated, but this should give you the gist.

[*] This step is a bit of a cheat. I'm ignoring a feature called "let generalization", which isn't needed in this context and which is actually disabled by several language extensions in GHC Haskell.

Comment: Just wanted to say how much I appreciate your answer. It’s excellent. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a type-derivation spreadsheet for this problem. It could be easier to follow having all the things right next to each other:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]

foldTree f = go  where
  go (Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)

foldTree f t = go t  where
  go t@(Node x ts) = f x (map go ts)
--------------------------------------
     Tree a                                  t  :: Tree a       from `data Tree a`
             a         a                     x  :: a            from `data Tree a`
              [Tree a]           [Tree a]    ts :: [Tree a]     from `data Tree a`
                              Tree a -> b    go :: Tree a -> b  from type of `map`
                          [b]                                   from type of `map`
               f  :: a -> [b] -> r                some resulting type `r`
               go :: Tree a   -> r                from definition of `go`
               go :: Tree a   -> b                as derived above
                     ----------------------
                               r ~ b              `r` and `b` are the same type
                     ----------------------
               f  :: a -> [b] ->   b              more precise type now
             ------------------------------
foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree    f               =  go
```

Here we started from the type of `t`, but whatever the starting point the derived type will always be the same, up to a consistent renaming of its type variables.

---

an explanation of this notation: we read this top to bottom, left to right. I tried to *align* the related things *vertically* in a suggestive manner. Imagine you annotate each entity with its type, writing the type near that entity on the sheet of paper with all the code on it (written in blue, say), in smaller letters and different color (say, red). Here, instead, we write the type under that entity, *vertically* aligned (even if there  are some other lines between them).

For example, the second line in the derivation section has two `a`s written under `x`s, with some more notes to the side. What does this all mean?

Each `a` is written under an `x`. It's like we've annotated each of the `x`'s with its type, `a`. Since `x` is the same `x` in both instances, the type is the same type. We don't yet know much about it, so we just call it `a` -- a type variable, capable of taking another, more refined meaning later, if it so happens further down in the process of inference. Then, there's a side note: `x :: a` is a regular Haskell notation, it means `x` has type `a`. So it says the same thing, but more formally. Then there's an informal note about where did this determination come from.

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me how should I read it ?

Comment: top to bottom, left to right. I tried to align the related things vertically in a suggestive manner. Imagine you annotate each entity with its type, writing the type near that entity on the sheet of paper with all the code on it, in smaller letters and different color. here, instead, we write the type _under_ that entity, vertically aligned, even if with several lines in between.

Comment: Thank you. This seems very interesting and I appreciate you sharing it. However, I do not understand. For example, the second line has two "a" and "x :: a". What does that mean ?

Comment: thanks for the questions! I've edited with more clarifications. :)

Comment: I've also posted some more [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+mechanical) on this topic before (quite a few, as it turns out), for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538099/849891)...

Comment: Thank you so much ! Will read your updated answer and links, carefully.

Comment: don't hesitate to ask if you need more clarifications. :)