# Power Function in Haskell: No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `**'

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
probIndex idx xs = 
  xs!!idx+mult
  where mult = round(2**idx)
```

When I try to load it in ghci, it shows the following error:

```
Prelude> :load bn.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bn.hs, interpreted )

bn.hs:31:16:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int)
      arising from a use of `round'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the expression: round (2 ** idx)
    In an equation for `mult': mult = round (2 ** idx)
    In an equation for `probIndex':
        probIndex idx xs
          = xs !! idx + mult
          where
              mult = round (2 ** idx)

bn.hs:31:23:
    No instance for (Floating Int)
      arising from a use of `**'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
    In the first argument of `round', namely `(2 ** idx)'
    In the expression: round (2 ** idx)
    In an equation for `mult': mult = round (2 ** idx)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Why does it occur? `2**idx` returns float, but `round` converts it to integer, so everything is an integer. Where do those "`Floating`" and "`RealFrac`" come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `xs!!idx+mult` is parsed as

```
(xs !! idx) + mult
```

The type of `(!!)` is

```
>> :t (!!)
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

which means that `idx :: Int`. Now you have

```
>>> mult = round (2 ** idx)
```

and the type of `(**)` is

```
>>> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

and since `idx :: Int` you can specialize to `(**) :: Floating Int => Int -> Int -> Int`, which is where you run into a problem - `Int` is not an instance of `Floating`. To get around this you can instead write

```
>>> mult = round (2 ** fromIntegral idx)
```

which will coerce `idx` into a fractional type, and satisfy the type checker. Alternatively, if the parsing of the original expression is not what you intended, you can simply replace it with

```
xs !! (idx + mult) where mult = ...
```

and your code should type check correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I am sorry for another newbie question. How to read (**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a ? I understand that a->a->a is a function which takes two arguments of type a and returns a value of type a, but how to interpret "Floating a =>"?

Comment: `Floating a =>` means "this type works for any type `a` that is an instance of `Floating`". So `a` can be `Float`, `Double` or a couple others (listed [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating))

Answer (score 4):

`(**)` is the power function for floating numbers. For integers you should use integer power `(^)`:

```
probIndex idx xs = 
  xs!!idx + 2^idx
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is parsed as

```
probIndex idx xs = (xs !! idx) + mult
  where mult = round (2**idx)
```

Now,

```
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: (Floating a) => a -> a -> a
```

which makes it `idx :: (Floating a) => a`, but

```
Prelude> :t (!!)
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

which makes it `idx :: Int`. Hence the unsuccessful attempts to find `(Floating Int)` instance. Similarly with `RealFrac` which comes from `round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`.

(*shameless plug:*  you can see more about type derivations e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558244/849891) :) ).