# Haskell operator or function for applying function from monad to a value?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm looking for a function or operator in Haskell that is effectively a `Monad` equivalent of the `Applicative` operator `<*>` that applies a monadic action rather than a bare function, that is instead of this:

`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

I'm looking for something that looks like this:

`... :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`

I can't believe that this isn't a standard function, but I can't see anything that matches.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be a simple composition of two other basic monad functions, namely [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) and [`ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap); since:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

we get:

```
(join .) . ap :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

as well as:

```
(join .) . (<*>) :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

or, using only bind operator, another construct would be:

```
(. (>>=)) . (>>=) :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Comment: What is `(join .)`?

Comment: @Kamel `join` applied to composition operator: `(join .) :: Monad m => (a -> m (m a1)) -> a -> m a1`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot `(.)` is an operator.  :)

Comment: @Kamel `((f .) . g) x y = f (g x y)`.

Comment: @behzad.nouri How could the type of `(join .)` be deduced? I am not able to connect `(.):: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` to the input of `join` which is `m (m a)`. Even though I know `(->)  a` is a functor.

Comment: @Kamel see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064 and [tag:pointfree] in general. And [tag:type-inference] for the type inference stuff, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/haskell-how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually.

Comment: And [tag:type-inference] for the type inference stuff, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/haskell-how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually.  --- `(join .)` is an operator section, same as `(.) join`.