# How does Haskell perform Beta conversion to derive a type?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, lambda-calculus, applicative, hindley-milner

I'm learning Haskell by taking [fp-course](https://github.com/tonymorris/fp-course) exercise. There is a [question](https://github.com/tonymorris/fp-course/blob/73a64c3d4d0df58654a1a9a0ee9d9b11c3818911/src/Course/FileIO.hs#L106) block my way. I don't know how Haskell infer `lift2 (<$>) (,)`'s type, and turn out `Functor k => (a1 -> k a2) -> a1 -> k (a1, a2)`.

I have tried out `lift2 (<$>)`'s type, and verified by GHCI's command `:t lift2 (<$>)`. step as follow.
I know `lift2 :: Applicative k => (a -> b -> c) -> k a -> k b -> k c`
I also know `(<$>) :: Functor f => (m -> n) -> (f m) -> (f n)`
Then by lambda calculus's Beta conversion, I can figure out `lift2 (<$>)`'s type is
`(Applicative k, Functor f) => k (m -> n) -> k (f m) -> k (f n)` by replacing `a` with `(m -> n)`, `b` with `(f m)`, `c` with `(f n)`

When I going to figure out `lift2 (<$>) (,)`'s type, It block me.
I know `(,) :: a -> b -> (a,b)`
And `lift2 (<$>) :: (Applicative k, Functor f) => k (m -> n) -> k (f m) -> k (f n)`.
How does Haskell apply `lift2 (<$>)` to `(,)`?
The first variable of `lift2 (<$>)` is `Applicative k => k (m -> n)`.
The to be applied value is `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)`
How the `k`, `m`, `n` replace by `a`, `b`?

GHCI's answer is `lift2 (<$>) (,) :: Functor k => (a1 -> k a2) -> a1 -> k (a1, a2)` by typing `:t lift2 (<$>) (,)`. I cannot infer out this answer by myself.

So I have 2 questions.
1.Could someone show me the inference step by step?
2.In this case the conversion seems not be Beta conversion in lambda calculus (May be I am wrong). What the conversion is?

Comment: You've got most of the way there. Haskell has to unify (ie, make equal) the types `Applicative k => k (m -> n)` and `a -> b -> (a, b)` - and can only do this by putting `k` equal to `(a ->)`, `m` to `b` and `n` to `(a, b)`. Then you end up with exactly the signature you started with for `liftA2 (<$>) (,)`.

Comment: Beta conversion is not used during type inference. No conversion here. Conversion (more properly, reduction) is a way to evaluate a term, trying to reduce it to normal form. Such evaluation is not needed during type inference. Inference roughly uses typing rules and unification, following an algorithm that has its roots in Hindley-Milner.

Comment: @chi isn't it practically the same thing though, rooted in the Modus Ponens? the "arr" terms `liftA2 = arr( {a->b->c} , {f a -> f b -> f c} ), fmap = arr( {d->e}, {h d -> h e} )` are like lambda terms, then it is like application, `liftA2 fmap = ...` where we "bind" the "parameter" (by unification) and substitute it in the "body" i.e. the second part of the "arr" term. something like that.

Comment: I've added two tags for you to browse and consult their info pages.

Comment: This is a very well-written question. You clearly laid out the work you did, why you feel stuck, and what you'd like to learn. Thank you for putting that effort in!

Comment: To elaborate on @RobinZigmond's comment: `k` unifies with `(a ->)` because the latter is a (applicative) functor (`Reader`) in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type derivation is a mechanical affair.<sup>(*)</sup> The key is that the function arrow `->` is actually a *binary* *operator* here, associating on the right (while the application / juxtaposition associates on the left).

Thus `A -> B -> C` is actually `A -> (B -> C)` is actually `(->) A ((->) B C)` is actually `((->) A) (((->) B) C)`. In this form it is clear that it consists of two parts so can match up with e.g. `f t`, noting the equivalences `f ~ ((->) A)` and `t ~ (((->) B) C)` (or in pseudocode `f ~ (A ->)`, and also `t ~ (B -> C)` in normal notation).

When "applying" two type terms a *structural unification* is performed. The structures of two terms are matched up, their sub-parts are matched up, and the resulting equivalences are noted as "substitutions" (`... ~ ...`) available to be performed and ensured in further simplifications of the resulting type terms (and if some incompatibility were to be thus discovered, the type would be then rejected).

This follows a general structure / type derivation rule rooted in the logical rule of Modus Ponens:

```
      A -> B     C
     --------------
           B         , where   A ~ C
```

And thus,

```
liftA2 :: A f =>       (   a     -> b   -> c  ) -> f      a         -> f b -> f c
       (<$>) :: F h =>  (d -> e) -> h d -> h e
             (,) ::                                s -> (t -> (s, t))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
liftA2 (<$>) (,) ::                                                    f b -> f c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  b ~ h d         f ~ (s->)
                        a ~ d->e         c ~ h e        a ~ t->(s,t)
                           \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ a ~ d->e
                       ----------------------------------------------------
                                                          d ~ t   e ~ (s,t)

liftA2 (<$>) (,) ::         f     b    -> f     c       
                  ~         (s -> b  ) -> (s -> c      )
                  ~  F h => (s -> h d) -> (s -> h e    )
                  ~  F h => (s -> h t) -> (s -> h (s,t))
```

(writing `A` for `Applicative` and `F` for `Functor`, as an abbreviation). The substitutions stop when there are no more type variables to substitute.

There's some freedom as to *which* type variables are chosen to be substituted on each step, but the resulting terms will be equivalent up to  *consistent renaming* of the type variables, anyway. For example we could choose

```
                  ~  F h => (s -> h d) -> (s -> h e    )
                  ~  F h => (s -> h d) -> (s -> h (s,t))
                  ~  F h => (s -> h d) -> (s -> h (s,d))
```

---

The `Applicative ((->) s)` constraint was discovered in the process. It checks out since this instance exists for all `s`. We can see it by typing `:i Applicative` at the prompt in GHCi. Looking through the list of instances it prints, we find `` instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in `Control.Applicative' ``.

If there were no such instance the type derivation would stop and report the error, it wouldn't just skip over it. But since the constraint holds, it just disappears as it does not constrain the derived type, `Functor h => (s -> h t) -> (s -> h (s,t))`. It's already "baked in".

The instance defines `(f <*> g) x = f x $ g x` but the definition itself is not needed in type derivations, only the fact that it exists. As for the `liftA2`, it is defined as

```
liftA2 h f g x = (h <$> f <*> g) x   -- for any Applicative (sans the `x`)
               = (h  .  f <*> g) x   -- for functions
               = (h . f) x (g x)
               = f x `h` g x         -- just another combinator
```

(yes, `(<*>) = liftA2 ($)` ), so

```
liftA2 (<$>) (,) g s = (,) s <$> g s
                     = do { r <- g s       -- in pseudocode, with
                          ; return (s, r)  --  "Functorial" Do
                          }
```

Or in other words, `liftA2 (<$>) (,) = \ g s -> (s ,) <$> g s`.

With the type `Functor m => (s -> m t) -> s -> m (s,t)`. Which *is* what we have derived.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> See also:

- [Haskell: how to infer the type of an expression manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558244/849891)

Comment: These tables are pretty cool, I should remind myself to use something like that when I need to work out some inference.

Comment: Thank you very much @Will. I even have a question about your answer.  
on the inference step `liftA2 (<$>) (,) :: f b -> f c`. I think maybe there should be a `Applicative f =>` or `Applicative (s ->)` constrain?   
However, even GHCI only constrain `h` by `Functor`, rather than constrain `(s ->)` or `f` by `Applicative`. GHCI turns out `lift2 (<$>) (,) :: Functor k => (a1 -> k a2) -> a1 -> k (a1, a2)`, rather than `lift2 (<$>) (,) :: (Functor k, Applicative (a1 ->))=> (a1 -> k a2) -> a1 -> k (a1, a2)`  
Why constrain `Applicative (s->) => ` disappeared?

Comment: because it holds by itself. it does not constraint the resulting `Functor h => ...` type. `Applicative ((->) s)` instance exists for any `s`. we can see it with `:i Applicative` at the prompt in GHCi, and looking through the list of instances it prints we find `instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in \`Control.Applicative'`. It is defined as `(f <*> g) x = f x $ g x` but the definition itself is not needed in type derivations, only the fact that it exists. if there were no such instance, the type checking would stop at that point and report the error, it wouldn't just skip over it.

Comment: I skipped over this part, implicitly, for simplicity, and kudos for noticing and for asking! another thing is that `s -> t -> (s, t)` = `s -> (t -> (s, t))` = `(->) s ((->) t (s,t))` = `((->) s) ((->) t (s,t))` and thus is naturally *structurally* matches with `f a`. both have two parts to them. (this I also only hinted at, at the answer).