# How to solve this Haskell type error? Expected and actual types do not match

Tags: haskell, typeerror, fold

I'm trying to extract all the largest integers from a list to another list using foldr and a helper function. My understanding of foldr is in conflict with the error messages. Here is my code:

```
largest :: [Int] -> [Int]
largest [] = []
largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs

largestHelper :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
largestHelper [] prev = [prev]
largestHelper (lrg : lrgs) prev | lrg < prev  = [prev]
                                | lrg == prev = prev : (lrg : lrgs)  
                                | otherwise   = (lrg : lrgs)
```

To me it looks like the first function to be evaluated is `largestHelper` with the last element of the integer list and `[]`. Next is `largestHelper` using the second last element of the list and the previous iteration which is simply the last element because it is the largest this far. And so on. So in the end `largest xs` has evaluated to a list which contains one or more integers with the largest value found from the given list.

Here are the errors:

```
largest.hs:3:20: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'
      Expected type: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
        Actual type: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
    * In the first argument of `foldr', namely `largestHelper'
      In the expression: foldr largestHelper [] xs
      In an equation for `largest':
          largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
  |
3 | largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

largest.hs:3:37: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Int]'
      Expected type: [[Int]]
        Actual type: [Int]
    * In the third argument of `foldr', namely `xs'
      In the expression: foldr largestHelper [] xs
      In an equation for `largest':
          largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
  |
3 | largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
  |
```

The first one seems to say that `largestHelper` is actually receiving two lists of integers instead of the one it is constructing. But doesn't `foldr` give elements of the list given to `largest` one by one and thus the second argument for `largestHelper` would indeed be an integer instead of a list of integers?
The second one seems to say that the argument for `largest` is actually `[[Int]]` instead of `[Int]`. I don't understand that.

I would appreciate very much clarification to this confusion. I don't know yet if this works, because it doesn't compile and as a total beginner in functional programming and Haskell, I would appreciate also comments considering the logic and style of the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two type errors follow the pattern `` Couldn't match type `foo' with `bar' `` and `` Couldn't match type `bar' with `foo' ``. The problem is you have the wrong argument order for `largestHelper`. `foldr` calls its function with the element first and the accumulator second, but `largestHelper` wants the accumulator first and the element second. Switch the order of them and your type error will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Let us break down the first error message:

> ```
> largest.hs:3:20: error:
> [...]
>   |
> 3 | largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
>   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

The compiler found a problem in your file `largest.hs` on line 3, column 20. It also gave a print out of the relevant line.

> ```
> * In the first argument of `foldr', namely `largestHelper'
>   In the expression: foldr largestHelper [] xs
>   In an equation for `largest':
>       largest xs = foldr largestHelper [] xs
> ```

The location is given again but this time in terms of argument, expression and equation. We learn that there is a problem with `largestHelper`.

> ```
> * Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'
>   Expected type: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
>     Actual type: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
> ```

The compiler expected `largestHelper` to be of type `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`, but found that the actual type of it is `[Int] -> Int -> [Int]`. Since they differ in `[Int]` versus `Int` the compiler reported an error.

So after looking at the error message we end up with two new questions:

- Why does the compiler expect `largestHelpler` to be of type `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`? This is the question about unification and there are some great answers over at [How to infer the type of an expression manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/haskell-how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually).
- How to fix the problem? This has been explained by [joseph-sible-reinstate-monica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68248794/1671066).

Note that the compiler was able to identify a problem because your programming language uses types. That is, types gave it the power to spot that there is something wrong with your code. So the compiler probably thinks of itself as your helpful companion when in reality it confronts you with the most bizarre and complicated technical jargon. And it is up to you to fix the problem.