# How to implement SKI combinators in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, lambda-calculus, combinators

I want to implement [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) in Prolog.

There are just 3 simple rules:

1. (I x) = x
2. ((K x) y) = x
3. (S x y z) = (x z (y z))

I came up with the following code by using [epilog](http://epilog.stanford.edu/homepage/):

```
term(s)
term(k)
term(i)
term(app(X,Y)) :- term(X) & term(Y)

proc(s, s)
proc(k, k)
proc(i, i)

proc(app(i,Y), Y1) :- proc(Y,Y1)
proc(app(app(k,Y),Z), Y1) :- proc(Y,Y1)
proc(app(app(app(s,P1),P2),P3), Y1) :- proc(app( app(P1,P3), app(P2, P3) ), Y1)

proc(app(X, Y), app(X1, Y1)) :- proc(X, X1) & proc(Y, Y1)
proc(X,X)
```

It works for some cases but has 2 issues:

1. It takes too much time to execute simple queries:

   ```
   term(X) & proc(app(app(k, X), s), app(s,k))
   ```

   100004 unification(s)
2. It requires multiple queries to process some terms. For example:

   ((((S(K(SI)))K)S)K) -> (KS)

   requires 2 runs:

   ```
   proc(app(app(app(app(s,app(k,app(s,i))),k),s),k),   X)    ==>
   proc(app(app(app(app(s,app(k,app(s,i))),k),s),k),   app(app(app(s,i),app(k,s)),k))

   proc(app(app(app(s,i),app(k,s)),k),    X)                 ==>
   proc(app(app(app(s,i),app(k,s)),k),    app(k,s))
   ```

Can you please suggest how to optimize my implementation and make it work on complex combinators?

*edit:* The goal is to reduce combinators. I want to enumerate them (without duplicates) where the last one is in normal form (if it exists of course).

Comment: what is your goal here? is it to reduce the combinators? (seems like it). there's usually multiple results, do you want to enumerate them all? in some order (like from shortest t longest)? *without duplicates*?

Comment: The goal is to reduce combinators. I want to enumerate them (without duplicates) where the last one is in normal form (if it exists of course).

Comment: For example: ((S K K) S) = (S K K S) = (K S (K S)) = S

Comment: aha, now it is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be implemented with iterative deepening like this:

```
term(s) --> "S".
term(k) --> "K".
term(i) --> "I".
term(a(E0,E)) --> "(", term(E0), term(E), ")".

reduce_(s, s).
reduce_(k, k).
reduce_(i, i).
% Level 1.
reduce_(a(s,A0), a(s,A)) :-
    reduce_(A0, A).
reduce_(a(k,A0), a(k,A)) :-
    reduce_(A0, A).
reduce_(a(i,A), A).
% level 2.
reduce_(a(a(s,E0),A0), a(a(s,E),A)) :-
    reduce_(E0, E),
    if_(E0 = E, reduce_(A0, A), A0 = A).
    % reduce_(A0, A). % Without `reif`.
reduce_(a(a(k,E),_), E).
reduce_(a(a(i,E),A), a(E,A)).
% level 3.
reduce_(a(a(a(s,E),F),A), a(a(E,A),a(F,A))).
reduce_(a(a(a(k,E),_),A), a(E,A)).
reduce_(a(a(a(i,E),F),A), a(a(E,F),A)).
% Recursion.
reduce_(a(a(a(a(E0,E1),E2),E3),A0), a(E,A)) :-
    reduce_(a(a(a(E0,E1),E2),E3), E),
    if_(a(a(a(E0,E1),E2),E3) = E, reduce_(A0, A), A0 = A).
    % reduce_(A0, A). % Without `reif`.

step(E, E0, E) :-
    reduce_(E0, E).

reduce_(N, E0, E, [E0|Es]) :-
    length(Es, N),
    foldl(step, Es, E0, E).

reduce(N, E0, E) :-
    reduce_(N, E0, E, _),
    reduce_(E, E), % Fix point.
    !. % Commit.
```

The term can be inputted and outputted as a list of characters with `term//1`. The grammar rule `term//1` can also generate unique terms.

```
?- length(Cs, M), M mod 3 =:= 1, phrase(term(E0), Cs).
```

The goal is to be as lazy as possible when reducing a term thus `dif/2` and the library [reif](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/metapredicates#if_3) is used in `reduce_/2`. The predicate `reduce_/2` does a single reduction. If any of the argument of `reduce_/2` is ground then termination is guarantee (checked with [cTI](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti)).

To reduce a term, `reduce_/4` can be used. The first argument specifies the depth, the last argument holds the list of terms. The predicate `reduce_/4` is pure and does not terminate.

```
?- Cs = "(((SK)K)S)", phrase(term(E0), Cs), reduce_(N, E0, E, Es).
```

The predicate `reduce/3` succeeds if there is a normal form. It is recommended to provide a maximum depth (e.g. `Cs = "(((SI)I)((SI)(SI)))"`):

```
?- length(Cs, M), M mod 3 =:= 1, phrase(term(E0), Cs), \+ reduce(16, E0, _).
```

Test with `((((S(K(SI)))K)S)K)`:

```
?- Cs0 = "((((S(K(SI)))K)S)K)", phrase(term(E0), Cs0), 
   reduce(N, E0, E), phrase(term(E), Cs).

   Cs0="((((S(K(SI)))K)S)K)", E0=a(a(a(a(s,a(k,a(s,i))),k),s),k), N=5, E=a(k,s), Cs="(KS)"
```

Comment: without looking into code, is it working by iterative deepening? Could you perhaps add a few words of explanation in general?

Comment: Yes, it is iterative deepening with `reduce_/4`.

Comment: @notoria I try to run $ Cs = "(((SK)K)S)", phrase(term(E0), Cs), reduce_(N, E0, E, Es). $ in https://swish.swi-prolog.org and it produces False. I have changed only if(..) to (p1 -> p2 ; p3). Can you please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Don't change `if_/3` with `(->)/2` and `(;)/2`. If `reif` isn't available then comment the `if_/3` lines and uncomment the ones following `if_/3`. And `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)` for SWI-Prolog.

Comment: what version of Prolog do you use?

Comment: I mainly use Scryer Prolog. I tested this solution with Scryer and SWI.

Comment: It works for reductions. I can not make it work for searching terms, for example: $N=10, reduce(N, a(a(a(a(s,  X  ),k),s),k), a(k,s)).$ runs forever, even the answer is simple: X=a(k,a(s,i)). Ideally, I want to get an answer for: reduce(N, a(a(X,s),k), a(k,s)). (find a term that swaps 2 terms)

Comment: When you run the query `?- reduce_(E0, a(k,s)).` there are multiple results (more than 2), you will be searching in a space that increases exponentially on depth. You need to guide the search like `?- N = 4, length(Cs, M), M mod 3 =:= 1, phrase(term(X), Cs), reduce(N, a(a(a(a(s, X ),k),s),k), a(k,s)).`.

Comment: Just a last question, why does `?- N = 4, length(Cs, M), phrase(term(X), Cs), reduce(N, a(a(X,s),k), a(k,s)).` works (even without specifying M) but when `length(Cs, M)` is removed it runs forever?  
And another one: why this query produces stack limit error: `?- N = 4, length(Cs12, M1),  length(Cs1, M2), length(Cs2, M3), M1=3, M2=2, M3=2,
phrase(term(F), Cs12), phrase(term(X1), Cs1), phrase(term(X2), Cs2),
reduce(N, a(F, X1), X2), reduce(N, a(F, X2), X1).`

Comment: That because of unfair enumeration (try `?- phrase(term(X), Cs).`). The stack error is because of `length/2` (simpler: `?- length(Cs, N), N=1.`).

Answer (score 2):

Translating your code trivially to Prolog, using the built-in *left-associating* infix operator `-` for `app`, to improve readability,

```
term(s).
term(k).
term(i).
term( X-Y ) :- term(X) , term(Y).

/* proc(s, s).      %%% not really needed.
proc(k, k).
proc(i, i). */

proc( i-Y, Y1) :- proc( Y,Y1).
proc( k-Y-Z, Y1) :- proc( Y,Y1).
proc( s-X-Y-Z, Y1) :- proc( X-Z-(Y-Z), Y1).

proc( X-Y, X1-Y1 ) :- proc( X, X1) , proc( Y, Y1).
proc( X, X).
```

executing in SWI Prolog,

```
26 ?- time( (term(X), proc( k-X-s, s-k)) ).
% 20 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-k ;
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-k ;
Action (h for help) ? abort
% 952,783 inferences, 88.359 CPU in 90.112 seconds (98% CPU, 10783 Lips)
% Execution Aborted
27 ?-
```

the first result is produced in 20 inferences.

---

Furthermore, indeed

```
32 ?- time( proc( s-(k-(s-i))-k-s-k, X) ).
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-i- (k-s)-k ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-i- (k-s)-k ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-i- (k-s)-k ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = s-i- (k-s)-k ;
% 11 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k- (s-i)-s- (k-s)-k ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k- (s-i)-s- (k-s)-k . % stopped manually
```

and then

```
33 ?- time( proc( s-i- (k-s)-k, X) ).
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k-s ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k- (k-s-k) ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k- (k-s-k) ;
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = k- (k-s-k) ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k-s ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k- (k-s-k) ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k- (k-s-k) ;
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k- (k-s-k) ;
% 3 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k-s ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = i-k- (k-s-k) . % stopped manually
```

but probably the result you wanted will still get generated directly, just after some more time.

Comment: BTW your [haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73878832/how-to-implement-the-next-type-inference-in-haskell) is really unclear.

Comment: but I invite you to browse through [my answers on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+%5Btype-inference%5D), esp. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually/14558244#14558244) with a rudimentary Prolog program for very simplified type inference.

Comment: I tried this code (SWI-Prolog online) and have 2 issues: 
"proc( k-Y-Z, Y1) :- proc( Y,Y1). Singleton variables: [Z]", "time( (term(X), proc( s-s-s, X)) )." produces infinite run

Comment: $time( (term(X), proc( X-k-s, s-k)) ).$ runs forever.

Comment: yes, I just translated your code, for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness) answer here is my solution:

```
term(s).
term(k).
term(i).
term(app(X,Y)) :- term(X), term(Y).

eq(s,s).
eq(k,k).
eq(i,i).
eq(app(X,Y),app(X,Y)).

proc(s, s).
proc(k, k).
proc(i, i).

proc(app(i,Y), Y1) :- proc(Y,Y1).
proc(app(app(k,Y),Z), Y1) :- proc(Y,Y1).
proc(app(app(app(s,P1),P2),P3), Y1) :- proc(app( app(P1,P3), app(P2, P3) ), Y1).

proc(app(X, Y), Z) :- proc(X, X1), proc(Y, Y1), eq(X, X1), eq(X, X1), eq(app(X, Y), Z).
proc(app(X, Y), Z) :- proc(X, X1), proc(Y, Y1), not(eq(X, X1)), proc(app(X1, Y1), Z).
proc(app(X, Y), Z) :- proc(X, X1), proc(Y, Y1), not(eq(Y, Y1)), proc(app(X1, Y1), Z).
```

1. Move code to [swish prolog](https://swish.swi-prolog.org). It works much faster

```
time((term(X), proc(app(app(k, X), s), app(s,k)))). 
% 356 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 3768472 Lips)
X = app(s,k)
```

2. Implemented complete reduction procedure:

```
proc(app(app(app(app(s,app(k,app(s,i))),k),s),k), X) 
answer contains: X = app(k,s)
```

There are still issues that I can not resolve

1. `time((term(X), proc(app(app(X, k), s), app(s,k)))).` runs forever
2. Answers are not ordered by reductions.