# How to implement the next type inference in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am interested to derive a [most general type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_type) of a hidden function from (input, output) pairs. Meaning we have types of input and output but do not have access to function.

All input, output and functions are [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus):

```
k::t1->t2->t1
k x y = x

s::(t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
s x y z = x z (y z)

i:: t1->t1
i x = x
```

For example, we have `(input, output) = (k:t1->t2->t1, kk:m1->m3->m4->m3)`. 
What is the most general type of a function that takes input and produces output? 
It is easy to guess: `f=k:f1->f2->f1`

```
(f k:t1->t2->t1):: m1->m3->m4->m3
```

How to implement this inference mechanism in Haskell?

I have found this [article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Determining_the_type_of_an_expression) but am stuck with implementation.

```
:t (\f -> let x = k in let y = f x in f) k
(t1 -> t4 -> t1) -> t5 -> t1 -> t4 -> t1
-- f is set to k and Haskell infers the correct type. In my case f is hidden.

:t (\f -> let x = k::a->b->a in let y = (f x)::t5 -> t1 -> t4 -> t1 in f)
-- This is my case: I know the type of x and y. The type of hidden f should be inferred
-- It does not infer a most general type of f and produces exception
```

Exception: *Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0 -> b0 -> a0) -> t2 -> t3 -> t7 -> t3’ with actual type ‘p’ because type variables ‘t2’, ‘t3’, ‘t7’ would escape their scope*

In this case, type of `f` should be `f1->f2->f1`, because Principal type algorithm for `(f1->f2->f1 a->b->a)` will derive `f2->a->b->a`.

Comment: "Does not work" means what? How do you expect it to "work"? In that last expression are you sure you have the parens in the place you want? the `::` applies for only the rhs `= (f x)`

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify my expectation from the working code. It produces exception and I do not know how to fix it and make it work. Is it clear now?

Comment: There is no most general type. `f _ = kk` has type `a -> m1 -> m3 -> m4 -> m3`, while `f' x _ = x` has type `a -> b -> a`. In both cases, `f k` has the same type as `kk`, but neither type is more general than the other.

Comment: (In fact, `f k = f' k = k k`, so it's not just that the output *type* matches for these functions, but in fact the actual output matches.)